# reading a csv file into a Networkx graph in python 3.5

Tags: python-3.x, csv, networkx

I am following this tutorial: [graph tutorial](https://zenagiwa.wordpress.com/2014/10/23/graphing-networks-for-beginners/) on my own data file. but I am getting stuck on the last bit. the code seems to throw:

```
(most recent call last)<ipython-input-193-7227d35394c0> in <module>()
      1 for node in links:  #loops through each link and changes each dictionary to a tuple so networkx can read in the information
      2     edges = node.items()
----> 3     G.add_edge(*edges[0])  #takes the tuple from the list and unpacks the tuples
      4 
      5 nx.draw(G)
TypeError: 'dict_items' object does not support indexing
```

is there a fix? I'm sort of stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably python-2 only compatible code.

In python 2, `dict.items()` returns a list of tuples (key, value) as opposed to `dict.iteritems()`

In python 3, `dict.iteritems()` has been removed, and `dict.items()` returns an iterator.
So you have to explicitly convert it to `list` to get access to the elements by index:

```
edges = list(node.items())
```